# Save new user in django user model and custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

Having trouble saving both the user to the built-in auth_user django model and my custom user model. My code saves the user to the django model but not my Account model.

models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
address = models.CharField(max_length=10)
addressNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20)
accountImage = models.CharField(max_length=999)





def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
     if created:
           profile, created = 
           Account.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
     address = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
     addressNumber = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
     image = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
     class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
              'password1', 'password2', 'address', 'addressNumber', 'image' )
```

and views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from myAccount.forms.userForm import AccountForm
from myAccount.models import Account
from myAccount.forms.forms import SignUpForm


 def register(request):
     form = SignUpForm(data=request.POST)
     if request.method == 'POST':
         if form.is_valid():
             account = form.save()
             account.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
             account.address = form.cleaned_data.get('address')
             account.addressNumber = form.cleaned_data.get('addressNumber')
             account.addressImage = form.cleaned_data.get('accountImage')
             account.save()
             raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
             return redirect('login')
     return render(request, 'myAccount/register.html', {'form': form})

 @login_required
 def seePurchasehistory(request):
     return render(request, 'myAccount/pruchaseHistory.html')

 @login_required
 def accountInfo(request):
     account = Account.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = AccountForm(instance=AccountForm, data=request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             account = form.save(commit=False)
             account.user = request.user
             account.save()
             return redirect('homepage-index')
     return render(request, 'myAccount/accountInfo.html', {
    'form': AccountForm(instance=account)
})
```

This is the guide I have been following: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html

EDIT:
With some changes( i updated the code above ) I now get the user id in my account table but the attributes I don't. So I'm guessing it has something to do with my register method.

Comment: This answered my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876774/django-extra-user-registration-details-not-saving-to-database

Answer (score 0):

you put at folder :

> static/myAccount/register.html

```
return render(request, 'myAccount/register.html', {'form': form})
```

i need you'r path ?

Comment: myAccount/register.html is in my templates folder. My path looks like this: https://pasteboard.co/J7lL0n6.png